# How to turn the exported .jar file into a .exe file so you can run it as and Exe?

Tags: java, jar, zip, exe

There is probably a duplicate or a simple question but I would just like to do this so I can add my game to a .zip directory so it takes up less space.

Comment: I know it is a dup but since that topic has closed and I tried the first 3 pages of answers and none of them worked I'm trying to see if something updated or something.

Comment: http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-to-exe.html Also "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Can telling how to turn a .jar file into an .exe file actually involve an *opinion* other than "don't do it (or don't use this method) because..."? Many questions asked at SO get unsolicited opinions (which isn't bad). A more appropriate criticism might be "Why don't you Google it?" which I did, and which led me here, which led me to the also-closed link above and to a truly-opinionated link suppled just above. Hence the up vote. Note that two others have marked this as a favorite. I had the same question, which is why I wound up here. I guess I won't be converting, now that I've read more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not used to working with JavaScript, but I am really good in Java. And when I do so, I use Launch4j. It is a really easy to use program, and it is made in Java. Here is where to find it:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/launch4j/files/launch4j-3/3.1.0-beta2/launch4j-3.1.0-beta2-win32.exe/download
Now when using Launch4J, what you do is open it, and there is going to be a bunch of Text Fields. The first one is Output File. Here you select where you want the EXE to go. Next one is Jar. Here you select what Jar you want to turn into windows executable. Now what you want to do is go up to the tabs, and go to where it says JRE, and there, under min JRE, i would say put 1.5.0 or 1.6.0. Now go back to basic. If you want an icon, and not just the regular windows one, make a PNG file of the icon. (note you will have to add one to the Java code if you want it in the program, this is just for the desktop icon.) then once you have your PNG, go and convert it to an ICO file. I suggest using http://www.convertico.com. Now you get that ICO file in the Icon button. Now you are done. click the gear icon at the top, and it will ask for you to make a new txt file. just save it wherever it really doesnt matter. you can delete it. Now you have it! Look where you put the EXE file and it should be there! Hope this helped you!

Comment: Thank you for the tutorial. That helped a ton.